# Rails 4 include and select

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

My models are:

```
class Person < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :archive, :dependent => :destroy

class Archive < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :person
```

Not all persons have archives, which means that `Person.find(xxx).archive` might return `nil`.

I need to return a partial set of attributes for all persons **with or without archives**.

When I do one of these:

```
Person.includes(:archive).select(:full_name)
Person.includes(:archive).select('persons.full_name')
```

I get only `full_name` of all persons, as expected.
Notice that I use `includes` and not `joins`, otherwise persons without archive are excluded from the result.

Then I tried to add to my select an attribute of `archive`:

```
Person.includes(:archive).select('persons.full_name', 'archives.title')
```

But then I get this warning:

> DEPRECATION WARNING: It looks like you are eager loading table(s) (one of: persons, archives) that are referenced in a string SQL snippet. For example:
>
> ```
>    Post.includes(:comments).where("comments.title = 'foo'")
> ```
>
> Currently, Active Record recognizes the table in the string, and knows to JOIN the comments table to the query, rather than loading comments in a separate query. However, doing this without writing a full-blown SQL parser is inherently flawed. Since we don't want to write an SQL parser, we are removing this functionality. From now on, you must explicitly tell Active Record when you are referencing a table from a string:
>
> ```
>    Post.includes(:comments).where("comments.title = 'foo'").references(:comments)
> ```
>
> If you don't rely on implicit join references you can disable the feature entirely by setting `config.active_record.disable_implicit_join_references = true`. (called from irb_binding at (irb):125)

Sooooo.. I simply added `references(:archive)` at the end of my statement:

```
Person.includes(:archive).select('persons.full_name','archives.title').references(:archive)
```

But now I get **all** attributes of person and **none** of archive.

I am sure that there is a clean and simple solution, but cannot find it. Some help please??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I think I found an answer.

This code works for me:

```
Person.joins("LEFT JOIN archives ON persons.id = archives.person_id")
      .select('persons.full_name', 'archives.title')
```

Till now I could not find any problem with it...

(I need to use LEFT JOIN since not all persons have archives, still I need to retrieve all persons)

BTW, I used this very-useful tutorial, in case you want to get some better understanding:
http://blog.arkency.com/2013/12/rails4-preloading/

Answer (score 0):

The title attribute is present, it's just that the default implementation of `inspect` only displays columns from the base table. You could do

```
Person.includes(:archive).select('persons.full_name','archives.title').
                          references(:archive).collect { |p| [p.full_name, p.title]}
```

to convince yourself of this.

If you do only need those 2 values, consider using `pluck` (although you'll need to be on rails 4.1 to use pluck to return multiple columns)

Comment: This solution _does not allow me to concatenate more scopes to it_ since it returns an array. It is not bad (although it is no precise - inside the collect loop it should be `p.archive.title`), but I would like to have it implemented as a scope.

Comment: As I said, this solution is not good since it returns an array.